# Javascript: regex matching/replacing not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following code:

```
    $('.numericOnly').change(function(e){
        var val = $(this).val();
        var replacedVal = val.replace(/^.*([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?).*$/, '$1');
        console.log(val);
        console.log(replacedVal);
    });
```

The console prints "234" and "4" when the input value is "234", and "8" when it is "234.8".

**Question**: Why?
**Goal**: I want to match a whole number, discarding any erroneous input.

E.g. if val is " 234.4", keep "234.4"; if val has any erroneous symbol, e.g. "a234.4b", I want to keep "234.4"; if val has ambiguous entries, like "234.4.5" or "234.4x23.5", I want to keep the first matcheable number instance ("234.4" in both cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `.*` is greedy. What happens is that the whole string is first matched by `.*` and then there's something called *backtracking* that occurs. That basically means that `.*` goes back one character at a time so that the rest of the regex can match.

Long story short, use something like this, which is lazy:

```
val.replace(/^.*?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?).*$/, '$1');
```

---

Description:

When the input is `234`, `.*` matches all of it, then goes back one character. At this particular point, `.*` is matching `23` and `([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?).*$` is matching `4`, which is perfectly acceptable and is why the match ends here.

When you use `.*?`, it first attempts to match 0 characters, then `([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?).*$`. This remaining part matches the whole number and the regex is again satisfied. That's the difference between lazy and greedy in simple terms.

---

Alternately, you could also just match a number with `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?` and put the match in `replacedVal`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?
```

without global `g` modifier